# Two fingers zooom in Chrome?

Tags: gestures

I would like to zoom with two fingers in Chrome on Ubuntu, as it works on Windows. Any chance that can be activated? When I use two fingers on my touchpad in Chrome nothing happens.

Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I you downvote, at least say how the qeustion could be improved. I think, it is pretty clear, and the answer is already posted below.

Answer (score 0):

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/09/enable-wayland-firefox-chrome/

> For Google Chrome, Chromium and their based web browsers, e.g., Edge, Vivaldi, just type chrome://flags/ in address bar and hit Enter. When the page opens, search for Preferred Ozone platform and use the dropdown menu to set it value to “Wayland“. Finally, click “Relaunch” button to apply change by restarting the web browser.